# C# WPF ScrollViewer scrolling locks a framerate at 30fps with a very low UI thread utilization percentage

Tags: c#, wpf, freeze, frame-rate

I am very confused, I see that UI thread is almost not loaded, timeline profiling tells me that my fps should be at least equal to 60, but the real fps unstable.

So, I have two ***VirtualizingStackPanel***, they both use a ***DoubleAnimation*** for smooth scrolling. The only one thing(that I know) they are different is that the first is created with xaml and is a ***ListView.ItemsPanelTemplate*** and is managed by ***ItemSource*** property of ListView; the second panel I created manually in code, manually set it as a ***Content*** of manually created ***ScrollViewer*** object and manually add every child to this panel.

The creation code:

```
private void InitializeItemsOwner()
{
    ItemsOwner = new VirtualizingStackPanel
    {
        Width = this.Width,
        Height = this.Height            
    };
    VirtualizingPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(ItemsOwner, true);
    VirtualizingPanel.SetCacheLengthUnit(ItemsOwner, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit.Item);
    VirtualizingPanel.SetCacheLength(ItemsOwner, new VirtualizationCacheLength(2));
    VirtualizingPanel.SetVirtualizationMode(ItemsOwner, VirtualizationMode.Recycling);
    UpdateFrameworkElement(ItemsOwner, RenderSize, new Rect(RenderSize));
    PreviewMouseWheel += Managers.AnimationManager.ListView_PreviewMouseWheel;
}

private void InitializeScrollOwner()
{
    ScrollOwner = new ScrollViewer()
    {
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled,
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled
    };
    ScrollOwner.Content = ItemsOwner;
    ScrollOwner.InvalidateScrollInfo();
    UpdateFrameworkElement(ScrollOwner, RenderSize, new Rect(RenderSize));
    this.Content = ScrollOwner;
}

/// <summary>
/// Updates layout of FrameworkElement object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">Framework element to update</param>
/// <param name="availableSize">Meashre with availableSize</param>
/// <param name="finalRect">Arrange with finalRect</param>
private void UpdateFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize, Rect finalRect)
{
    element.Measure(availableSize);
    element.Arrange(finalRect);
    element.UpdateLayout();
}
```

[Here is a Profiler screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwmXf.png) which, I hope, shows all important info.
The first panel scrolling is at the left part of profiling screenshot, the second panel - at the right. We can see, that first panel loads UI thread much more because of a bit expensive layout and code operations, but it has a stable 60 fps; the second panel, which is created in code loads UI thread much less than the first panel scrolling, but nevertheless it drops a framerate down to 30 as it woulld be locked at 30 fps. I think it's very strange behaviour for such a simple. The important thing is that both the stackPanel objects has less than 40 children, I checked it in a Live Visual Tree window.

As I mentioned above I add children to the second panel in code, every child is an Image control with a Source property set. Here is a code of child adding method:

```
private void AddChild(BitmapSource image)
{
    Image imageControl = new Image
    {
        Source = image,
        SnapsToDevicePixels = true,
        UseLayoutRounding = true
    };
    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(imageControl, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);
    imageControl.Effect = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.DropShadowEffect()
    {
        Color = Colors.Black
    };
    imageControl.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
    Size imageSize = new Size(image.Width, image.Height);
    ItemsOwner.Children.Add(imageControl);

    UpdateFrameworkElement(imageControl, imageSize, new Rect(imageSize));
    ItemsOwner.UpdateLayout();
}
```

So a very interesting thing for me is that if replace this ***Image*** control with some Rectangle any other simple control the lock at 30fps disappear and I have a smooth 60fps during scroll animation. The problem is in this ***Image*** control, arrangement of such instance is heavy for some reason, but why a Profiler doesn't tell anything about it? Could I miss something important with ***Image*** instance creation? If yes, what can I try to solve this problem?
Thank you, if you need some additional details please let me know. Waiting for your thoughts..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, the problem is in ***DropShadowEffect***. Arrangement of the second panel items cause their shadow effects to be recalculated/redrawn or something like that. So The solution is to get rid of ***DropShadowEffect*** at all, or you can use a ***RenderTargetBitmap*** to render the whole control with shadow effect to a BitmapSource object like it is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1). So the question is closed!